# How to Set SSL to a localhost server which is supported by all the browsers?

Tags: sockets, ssl, browser, configuration, localhost

I have a windows desktop application which need to be communicated with our web page.So I've created a local server which runs on a port.I'm creating a socket from my webpage to the desktop application and the communication happens though that socket.

As my webpage runs on HTTPS, I need to create a secure socket ('wss'). SO I generated a self signed certificate for Ip 127.0.0.1 using openssl and I imported the certificate to windows trusted cerificate store.Now google chrome accepts it as a trusted certificate but the firefox rejects that certificate with the error [Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BI3D.png) .

We cant buy a SSL certificate for localhost domain from a CA. Is there any solution to overcome this problem? Is there any way to skip SSL check for socket creation?

How can I create a certificate which will be accepted by all the browsers as a trusted certificate?

Answer (score 3):

Firefox can use the desktop store by setting this key to TRUE : security.enterprise_roots.enabled

To change this, open about:config with your Firefox and look for this key.

If you want to change this automatically for several desktops, have a look at this [tutorial](https://support.umbrella.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000669728-Configuring-Firefox-to-use-the-Windows-Certificate-Store) which is well done.

Answer (score 2):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48558621/2657515) from [Eugène Adell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7748072/eug%c3%a8ne-adell) is good, but if you are on Linux, a policy file is required to trust the OS certificate authority.

Create a file "policies.json" in the "distribution" directory of the Firefox install location, and point it to the certificate file:

```
{
  "policies": {
    "Certificates": {
      "ImportEnterpriseRoots": true,
      "Install": ["localhost.crt","/path/to/cert/file"]
    }
  }
}
```

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/setting-certificate-authorities-firefox
https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md#certificates--install

---

*This Q&A on a similar question may have some more information:*
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74802552/2657515

Comment: the question is old and about Windows, but still, thanks for contributing.